# Detected android device connected to PC

Tags: java, android, .net, detect

I have an android device, I wish to know when it is connected to the PC via Java/.NET.
I know it's possible - the Samsung New PC Studio is doing it. Whenever I connect an android device it lets me know. how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 4):

You have to listen for one of this notifications

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

If you're using it as a mass storage device then use this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED

Other USB events aren't clearly described in the documentation

EDIT:
If you want to read on the computer side I would read this article

http://today.java.net/article/2006/07/05/java-and-usb

and then check which kind of devices are connected to the usb port. if it is a mobile phone, then you can try to send a short message to it. on your phone you make a small piece of code which returns an appropriate answer so you can detect thats its really android/your phone/this phones you want to identify

Comment: Those are for the case where you want to detect on the device if the device is connected. The Samsung PC Studio Manager is a Windows desktop program, as near as I can tell.

Comment: Ah ok sry then i misunderstood the question. But if its necessary to detect on the PC, then i don't rellay need code on Android, but instead some programm on the pc which checks the ubs ports

Answer (score 0):

java device detection

This site have a guide on how to detect device with java web and java core

http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/Java/GettingStarted.aspx