# Detect whether Android is connected to computer via USB

Tags: java, android, usb

Is there a way (hopefully system independent) to detect whether an Android Device is connected to a computer via USB using Java.

Comment: Check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935249/detected-android-device-connected-to-pc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935249/detected-android-device-connected-to-pc)

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229024/878126 . this will tell you if currently the device is connected or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://today.java.net/article/2006/07/05/java-and-usb

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this will get me started.

Comment: Link is dead. Could you please share it again?